# How to solve this problem by induction method, and derive neumann formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, education, computational-mathematics

Some explaination would be helpful

> if$\quad$
>   $a^n = a(a - h)....[a - (n - 1)h ]$ $\quad$ and $\quad$ $a^0=1$ $\quad$ then $\qquad$ prove $\quad$
>   $(a + b)^n = \sum_{m=0}^n C_n^m a^{n - m} b^{m}$,

Comment: Do induction on $n$. The basis case for $n=0$ is $(a+b)^0=\sum_{m=0}^{0} C_0^m a^{-m}b^m$. Both sides are equal to $1$. The inductive step is more difficult.

Comment: What is $h$ supposed to be ?

Comment: I have no idea , the question is as it is.

Comment: and i need to do the inductive step

Comment: This is simply the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: where can i find it in an understandable form ?